# Suggestion Needed about Design Experiment

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

As a part of my coursework, I'm supposed to be designing an experiment for an online cab service provider to understand the following:

1. Whether letting the cab driver know the drop location of the passenger before accepting the booking reduces ride cancellation by the driver
2. Whether incentivising  the cab driver for 0 cancellation over a week helps in reducing ride cancellation

The dependent variable for both these experiments is ratio of completed rides to total rides booked. I want to split the total number of drivers into 2 groups - 50% experimental & 50% control and run the experiments one at a time. But in this way, I'm unable to understand the interaction between the 2 treatments. Therefore, what I have decided is to create 4 groups of 25% each - Group A gets Treatment 1, Group B gets Treatment 2, Group C gets both Treatments 1 & 2, Group D gets no treatment at all. Is this approach correct? Is there a better alternative to this? I'm new to this topic, hence any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume that drivers communicate with one another. Especially if you have four different groups, drivers will wonder why they are being treated differently for reasons they don't understand and that communication could lead to unexpected ride-cancelling behaviors.

Comment: Hi BruceET, they probably can communicate but the chances are low. For example, in Uber the drivers are independent contractors with their own cars. Less chances of interaction among each other there. They take bookings as they please.

Comment: Your proposed design good place to start. What you describe is a 2-factor 2-level full factorial design. I'd suggest reading up on factorial designs to understand them in more detail.